# ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 1000) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

Trying to train a Resnet50 model from it's pre trained form but once it hits the code of training it, it throws this error `ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 1000) are incompatible` I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here?

I have 5 classes dataset so that's why I am using `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss.

Full code is here:

```
    # This is in for loop until labels.append
    #load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)

    data.append(image)
    # extract the class label from the image path and update the
    # labels list
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    labels.append(label)
  

  print("[INFO] ...reading the images completed", "+ Label class extracted.")

  # scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
  data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
  labels = np.array(labels)
  print("[INFO] data matrix: {:.2f}MB".format(
      data.nbytes / (1024 * 1000.0)))
  # binarize the labels
  lb = LabelBinarizer()
  labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
  # partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
  # the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
  (trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

  model = ResNet50()

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

  print("[INFO] Model compilation completed.")
  # train the network
  print("[INFO] training network...")
  H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS,
                validation_data=(testX, testY),
                steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
                epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a layer with the proper number of categories for your task:

```
base = ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg')

out = K.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')

model = K.Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=out(base.output))
```

Comment: So, the `ResNet50()` should be given the arguments for classes? Anyways, I will be trying this and will let you know in a bit.

Comment: You should read this: https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/#resnet50-function

Comment: It throws an error saying that `ValueError: If using `weights as `"imagenet"` with `include_top` as true, `classes` should be 1000` and when I put it to `false` then it throws this error: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 7, 7, 2048) are incompatible`

Comment: Implementing your edited one resulted into this: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 2048) are incompatible`

Answer (score 1):

You have used the fully connected layers of the pre-trained ResNet, you need to create your appropriate classification layers suitable for your task.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model

model = ResNet50(include_top=False)
f_flat = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model.output)          
fc = Dense(units=2048,activation="relu")(f_flat)
logit = Dense(units=5, activation="softmax")(fc)

model = Model(model.inputs,logit)
```

Comment: This actually works but the `val_accuracy` is around 20 whereas the `acc` is around 80-90. Could it because of my lower dataset?

Comment: Yes maybe, try to added a dropout layer and reduce the numbre of units in the fc layer :

`from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout`
`fc = Dense(units=512,activation="relu")(f_flat)`
`fc = Dropout(0.2)(fc)`
`

Comment: Do I have to add all of the above stated into your code above or replace it? However, adding it to the above code did not change anything. I am guessing it is the datasets.

Comment: Add it like this:

`from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D,Dropout`
`from tensorflow.keras import Model`

`model = ResNet50(include_top=False)`
`f_flat = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model.output)`          
`fc = Dense(units=512,activation="relu")(f_flat)`
`fc = Dropout(0.2)(fc)`
`logit = Dense(units=5, activation="softmax")(fc)`

`model = Model(model.inputs,logit)`

if it doesn't work then the problem is in your data or in your preprocessing step..

Comment: Nevermind, it started pretty slow for the `val_acc` and then gradually increased to 80-90 for each epoch.